# NFQ demo: why all my netfilter example not works?

Tags: netfilter

In Suricata, it using the NFQ to implement it's IPS(invade protect service) feature, but on my case, the NFQ not works as expected(My kernel is 3.11), and I write a simplified demo to test the NFQ feature:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/time.h> /* timeval */ 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h>

#define NFQ_NUM 4
#define QUEUE_MAXLEN 4096

static int nfq_cb(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *msg, struct nfq_data *nfa, void *data) {
    return 0;
}

int nfq_demo(void) {
    struct nfq_handle *h = nfq_open();
    if (!h) {
        return -1;
    }

    /* here, failed on nfq_unbind_pf */
    if (nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
        printf("nfq_unbind_pf failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (nfq_unbind_pf(h, AF_INET6) < 0) {
        printf("nfq_unbind_pf failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (nfq_bind_pf(h, AF_INET) < 0) {
        printf("nfq_bind_pf failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (nfq_bind_pf(h, AF_INET6) < 0) {
        printf("nfq_bind_pf failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* if comment above bind/unbind, the create fail too */
    struct nfq_q_handle *qh = nfq_create_queue(h, NFQ_NUM, nfq_cb, NULL);
    if (!qh) {
        printf("nfq_create_queue failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* ... */
}

int main() {
    nfq_demo();
    return 0;
}
```

I have set my iptables like that:

```
iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE
iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE
```

and I checked the `/proc/net/netfilter/`, there is nothing except the `nf_log`:

```
0 NONE ()
1 NONE ()
2 NONE ()
3 NONE ()
4 NONE ()
5 NONE ()
6 NONE ()
7 NONE ()
8 NONE ()
9 NONE ()
10 NONE ()
11 NONE ()
12 NONE ()
```

What's wrong with my NFQ demo?

The second question is, all the NFQ settings works well when I debug Suricata, when `curl google.com`, there will be a HTTP request send to Google, but the call `recv` on the socket related to the NFQ **always** return -1 and means nothing received(and `curl` timeout), why this happen?

Answer (score 3):

Got the first answer, run the program as root, and all NFQ APIs works as expected.